# Wireshark in Mac couldn't parse HTTP in TCP payload

Tags: macos, http, tcp, wireshark

I am using mac os with version 10.15.7, with Wireshark version 3.4.4, couldn't parse the http info in the TCP payload though can follow TCP stream to view http info, what should i do now? in analysis, I enabled all protocol. and the ports for the TCP include 80 and 50263.

[Picture of TCP payload in mac OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S62yg.png)

[Picture of HTTP/TCP packets parsed in window OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkhpx.png)

I want the wireshark in Mac OS can parse the TCP payload in the format of HTTP packet as that in window OS. Above pictures are with same packet but parsed in Mac OS and window OS.

test_http_tcp.pcap

Comment: The image you show does not provide any useful information. Your problem cannot be reproduced or otherwise analyzed with this. Please provide the packet capture you are trying to display as file instead in your question and point out exactly which packet in this capture you have problems with.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please prefer code than image : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Thanks for your reply. please see my updated attached files.

Comment: How to attach a pcap file?